# How to remove entries from a nested list that are shorter than a given length

Tags: python, string, list, filtering, nested-lists

I have a nested list with several sublists like this:

```
l = [
    ...
    ['22.06.2009', 'https://hoew.de/ha/xx']
    ...
    ]
```

But there also some entries like:

```
U= [
    ...
   ['22.06.2009', '/']
   ['22.06.2009', 'hiw']
   ...
   ]
```

Now I want to delete the sublists which have entries at the [1] index which are too short (less than 5 characters).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a list comprehension through the matrix, which we can call `unfiltered_matrix`, a `candidate` can only be considered if his second element has a length that greater than 5. The result will be a `filtered_matrix`.

```
filtered_matrix = [candidate for candidate in unfiltered_matrix if len(candidate[1] >= 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [
    ['22.06.2009', 'https://hoew.de/ha/xx'],
    ['22.06.2009', '/'],
    ['22.06.2009', 'hiw']
    ]

>>> [x for x in l if len(x[1]) >= 5]
[['22.06.2009', 'https://hoew.de/ha/xx']]
```